# MySQL 5.5. installation on Windows doesn't show up in the registry properly

Tags: windows, mysql-python

I am trying to get `Django` with MySQL working on my Windows 7 machine.
I need mySQLDB interface for this. When I try to install "mySQLDB interface", it looks for the MySQL installation in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.
But in my registry it shows up in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/MySQL AB/MySQL Server 5.5`.

My SQL instance seems to work fine.

MySQLDB installer somehow needs this in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (I think) as it doesn't let me finish the install. It throws me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "C:\Blah\Software\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.
py", line 8, in get_config
mysql_root, dummy = _winreg.QueryValueEx(serverKey,'Location')
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the registry key in `site.cfg`. Or you can download a [Windows MSI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/latest/download) package from SourceForge. (No, it did not exist when the question was posted.)